# What is the recommended way to break out of a block or stop the enumeration?

Tags: ios, loops, swift, break

So, I just realize that break is only for loop or switch.

[image]

Here's my question: Is there a recommended way to break out of a block? For example:

```
func getContentFrom(group: ALAssetsGroup, withAssetFilter: ALAssetsFilter) {
    group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock { (result, index , stop) -> Void in

        //I want to get out when I find the value because result contains 800++ elements
    }
}
```

Right now, I am using return  but I am not sure if this is recommended. Is there other ways? Thanks folks.

Comment: Blocks are like separate functions.  You can't "break" out of them, you can only return.

Comment: Are you asking how to stop the current iteration, or how to completely stop the enumeration altogether?

Comment: Thanks for the comment borrrden

Hi @Rob, I wanted to stop the current iteration. But I am guessing it that will also mean stoping the enumeration? Reading on it now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to stop the current iteration of the enumeration, simply `return`.

But you say:

> I want to get out when I find the value because result contains 800++ elements

So, that means that you want to completely stop the enumeration when you find the one you want. In that case, set the boolean value that the `pointer` points to. Or, a better name for that third parameter would be `stop`, e.g.:

```
func getContentFrom(group: ALAssetsGroup, withAssetFilter: ALAssetsFilter) {
    group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock() { result, index, stop in

        let found: Bool = ...

        if found {
            //I want to get out when I find the value because result contains 800++ elements

            stop.memory = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`return` is fine, block concept is similar to function, so returning is okay.